# Allow HTTP access to external interface

Tags: iptables, http, nat

How can I allow HTTP access to $EXTIF?

```
*nat
-A POSTROUTING -o "$EXTIF" -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0] #If this is changed to DROP than clients cannot connect out.
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A FORWARD -i "$EXTIF" -o "$INTIF" -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i "$INTIF" -o "$EXTIF" -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LOG
-A OUTPUT -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LOG
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow only HTTP to $EXTIF:

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESSTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i $EXTIF -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
iptables -P INPUT DROP
```

This will allow outsiders only to initiate connections to port 80 (HTTP) of your server. The established/related rule will allow the server only to reply to these connections, so this satisfies your requirements, I think.

This should also fairly effectively flood your log with packets to ports different than 80. I'd consider limit rule in the -j LOG section.

NAT prevents any outside entity from initiating a direct connection to anything behind the NAT. You do not need to do anything extra to protect the NATted network from port scanning. Keeping the individual hosts firewalled and with a current anti-virus software (if it's a MS OS) is still a recommended thing.

Take some time to read Rusty's Remarkably Unreliable Guides (http://people.netfilter.org/~rusty/unreliable-guides/) and iptables man pages too. They are well-written.

Comment: I do not need to provide HTTP access to the NAT host, I would like to only allow the host and internal clients to access HTTP. The DROP rule on the INPUT kills connectivity for the NAT host.

Comment: If no HTTP connectivity is needed on $EXTIF, then replace $EXTIF with $INTIF -- this will open port 80.

Comment: When I mentioned HTTP, I meant that users should only be able to access external HTTP(S) websites. The NAT host does not actually host any HTTP resources. Currently, a user can access any resource via NAT and I would like to limit that to HTTP(S) only. I have updated the script to what I currently have.